# Couldn't find `activityViewModels()` Hilt Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt

I'm using Hilt and MVVM at my project and I want to get an `viewModel` from `activityViewModel` to use same in 2 activites. But my Android Studio says Unresolved Reference.

My app build.gradle is like this:

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'kotlin-android'
        id 'kotlin-kapt'
        id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    }
```

. . .

```
dependencies {

. .  .

implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1"

implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
. . .
}
```

My project build.gradle file is like this:

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'
```

I'm trying to get `ViewModel` like this:

```
private val viewModel: SelectWifiViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry, I'm fixing that now. Thanks for tip.

Comment: Is that code within a Fragment?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Seeing it now but have the right Gradle dependencies. It must be something simple.

Answer (score 3):

`activityViewModels()` has nothing to do with Hilt

you need a different dependency for that. It is in

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0"
```

Comment: I've tried adding this but again says Unresolved Reference

Comment: @EmanuelGarcia did you sync gradle after adding it?

Comment: Yes I sync every time I add/remove dependencies.

Comment: @EmanuelGarcia can you try writing `import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels` in the file you want to use it?

Comment: I also tried that and again says Unresolved reference :/.

Comment: I also try to replace `by activityViewModels()` with `by androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels()`

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably missing is that `activityViewModels` [is an extension function on `Fragment`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:fragment/fragment-ktx/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentViewModelLazy.kt;l=147?q=FragmentViewModelL). Therefore, calling it from an `Activity` will result in an unresolved reference.

If you want to get a `ViewModel` instance from within the activity, then you should:

1.Inherit from [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity) rather than `Activity`. This is because the former implements `ViewModelStoreOwner`, while the latter does not. Make sure you have a dependency on `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` for that.

2.Use [`ViewModelProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider) to fetch a `ViewModel` instance:

```kotlin
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[SelectWifiViewModel::class.java]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    def fragment_version = "1.4.0"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    // Testing Fragments in Isolation
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment

Comment: I've tried adding this but again says Unresolved Reference

Answer (score 1):

by `activityViewModels()` is a Kotlin property delegate from the `fragment-ktx` library.

try to add this dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

`activityViewModels` is used to get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to its Activity inside a fragment. If you want to used same ViewModel in both the activities, I would suggest you to switch to Fragments instead.