# Will I get the same instance of ViewModel() when I use Hilt as DI in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I use Hilt as as DI in Android Studio project, I know there are two ways to create the instance of `ViewModel()`.

**Way 1**

```
way1: RecordSoundViewModel = hiltViewModel()
```

**Way 2**

```
val way2: RecordSoundViewModel by viewModels()
```

1: Coudl you tell me if `viewModel1`, `viewModel2`, `viewModel3` and `viewModel4` is the same instance of `RecordSoundViewModel`?

2: If the four instances are not the same instance of `RecordSoundViewModel`, how can I get the same instance?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActivityMain : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)     
        val viewModel3: RecordSoundViewModel by viewModels()
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        val viewModel4: RecordSoundViewModel by viewModels()
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Line(    
    viewModel1: RecordSoundViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

}

@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Recording(   
    viewModel2: RecordSoundViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

}



@HiltViewModel
class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    ...
): ViewModel()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: That depends entirely on if there is anything in between the activity and `ScreenHome_Line` / `ScreenHome_Recording`. Any Fragment, `NavHost`, or anything else that would create a more narrow `ViewModelStoreOwner` scope would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the same viewmodel instance.

It is understood when the source code is examined.

```
public class ViewModelLazy<VM : ViewModel> @JvmOverloads constructor(
    private val viewModelClass: KClass<VM>,
    private val storeProducer: () -> ViewModelStore,
    private val factoryProducer: () -> ViewModelProvider.Factory,
    private val extrasProducer: () -> CreationExtras = { CreationExtras.Empty }
) : Lazy<VM> {
    private var cached: VM? = null

    override val value: VM
        get() {
            val viewModel = cached
            return if (viewModel == null) {
                val factory = factoryProducer()
                val store = storeProducer()
                ViewModelProvider(
                    store,
                    factory,
                    extrasProducer()
                ).get(viewModelClass.java).also {
                    cached = it
                }
            } else {
                viewModel
            }
        }

    override fun isInitialized(): Boolean = cached != null
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get the same instance both `Activity` and `Compose` ?

Comment: proof that you have already received your code.

Comment: Thanks!  viewModel2, viewModel3 are different instance

Comment: You need to use activityviewmodels.As long as the Activity lives, it will survive. :)

Comment: And more, I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214316/couldnt-find-activityviewmodels-hilt-android

Comment: Thanks! I use `val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[RecordSoundViewModel::class.java]` to create instance in Activity, but it's a different instance from `RecordSoundViewModel = hiltViewModel()`

Comment: Have you tried using shareviewmodel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76293782/5595926

Comment: Thanks!  How can I use  shareviewmodel? in Activity

Comment: You can use it via navigation.